# Convert mm to hh:mm

Tags: linux, bash, awk, python, date

I am using `awk` to get all of the 4th comma-delimited fields, which is a duration in minutes. The required output is in the format of hh:mm, so I need to convert that from minutes.

```
"jone","spdb-deploy","SD",25
"abrham","Data-deploy","DD",5
"crater","aps-deploy","AD",25
"valu","Platform-deploy","PD",5
"kiol","teer-deploy","TD",180
```

```
$ cat dat.csv | awk -F',' '{print $4}'
25
5
25
5
180
```

...above values are in minutes, I want those values to be printed as hh:mm like below:

```
00:25
00:05
00:25
00:05
03:00
```

Comment: I would encourage you to prefer a format such as 1h20m instead of 01:20 to avoid ambiguity with 1 minute and 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the formatted printing function, like

```
> awk -F, '{$4 = sprintf("%02d:%02d", int($4/60), $4%60)}1' OFS=, file
"jone","spdb-deploy","SD",00:25
"abrham","Data-deploy","DD",00:05
"crater","aps-deploy","AD",00:25
"valu","Platform-deploy","PD",00:05
"kiol","teer-deploy","TD",03:00
```

Answer (score 4):

Using your script:

```
awk -F',' '{print $4}' dat.csv
```

change it on this way:

```
awk -F',' '{h=int($4/60);m=$4%60;printf "%02d:%02d\n", h,m}' dat.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use
`cat dat.csv | awk -F',' '{printf("%02d:%02d\n", $4/60, $4%60)}'`
It should work. Good thing about this is if you already know C's printf it is straightforward to understand what is doing.

Comment: `cat file | awk '…'` is pretty much the same as `awk '…' file`